# Is there an way to get an accurate count of testng tests via Sonar or Hudson?

Tags: java, unit-testing, hudson, testng, sonarqube

Hudson and/or Sonar seem to report the number of test invocations, but not the number of tests.

So if you have

```
@Test(invocationCount=1000)
testFoo() {}
```

Both hudson and sonar will say there are 1000 tests when there really is only one.  Other than wc'ing the number of @Test tags, is there a way to see this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way to get what you want in Sonar.

It's true that with the basic example that you gave, showing that there are 1000 tests in Sonar can be misleading. However, I can't believe this is a common use case to run a test repeatedly without changing its data (i.e. running **exactly** the same test several times).

However, for Sonar side, feel free to come on our user mailing list (user@sonar.codehaus.org) to discuss this.

Comment: First - thanks for a great piece of software.  Multi-threaded tests running on multi-core machines can vary subtly from run to run.  We commonly test thread-safe code by lining up hundreds of threads behind a barrier and then let them loose on some piece of code that is supposed to be thread safe.  Subtle bugs in our code have lead to some failures maybe 50 out of 1000 times.  So this is why we repeat the tests over and over.